# How to divide 32-bit number by a 16 bit number in avr assembly?

Tags: assembly, avr, division

I am trying to make a function that divides an unsigned 32-bit number by an unsigned 16-bit number in AVR assembly language. Since I am using a ATmega128 micro-controller I don't have the ability to use the div instruction, which most examples that I can find seem to use. I have also been trying to just come up with an algorithm to do this division with no such luck. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: libgcc should have a 32/32 => 32-bit division function you could call (e.g. look at C compiler output for division of `uint32_t` vars).  It might check for upper zeros, but you can probably do better by hand (especially for code-size since you can leave out the unused code-paths entirely).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a bit-wise division. This is basically a longhand division like we learned in grade school, but using base 2 instead of base 10. This simplifies  quotient digit selection, where each digit is a single bit, of course. In each step, if the partial remainder is greater than or equal to the divisor, subtract the divisor from the partial remainder, and record the least significant quotient digit as one.

In a classical arrangement, one starts out with a pair of registers overlaying the dividend, such that the most significant half of the dividend is in the remainder register, and the least-significant half of the dividend in the quotient register. Each step begins by left shifting the concatenated register pair. This appends the next dividend bit to the partial remainder, while creating room for the next quotient bit at the least-significant end of the quotient register. After cycling for as many bits as there are bits in the divisor, all the dividend bits have been shifted out of the quotient register, which now holds only the collected quotient bits.

As ISO-C99 code, this algorithm, typically called the non-performing binary division, looks like shown below. AVR is an 8-bit architecture providing byte-sized registers `r0` through `r31`, and I have annotated in the comments how I plan to map operands in the C code to registers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t udiv_32_16 (uint32_t dividend, uint16_t divisor)
{
    // dividend in r3:r2:r1:r0, divisor in r5:r4
    uint16_t quot = dividend;        // r1:r0
    uint16_t rem  = dividend >> 16;  // r3:r2
    uint8_t  bits = 16;              // r6
    uint8_t  carry;                  // carry flag
    do {
        // (rem:quot) << 1, with carry out
        carry = rem >> 15;
        rem  = (rem << 1) | (quot >> 15);
        quot = quot << 1;
        // if partial remainder greater or equal to divisor, subtract divisor
        if (carry || (rem >= divisor)) {
            rem = rem - divisor;
            quot = quot | 1;
        }
        bits--;
    } while (bits);
    return quot;
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t dividend;
    uint16_t divisor, quotient, ref, dividend_hi;

    dividend = 1;
    do {
        printf ("\rdividend=%08x", dividend);
        dividend_hi = dividend >> 16;
        divisor = 1; 
        while (dividend_hi < divisor) {
            ref = dividend / divisor;
            quotient = udiv_32_16 (dividend, divisor);
            if (quotient != ref) {
                printf ("\n!!!! dividend=%08x  divisor=%04x  quotient=%04x  ref=%04x\n", dividend, divisor, quotient, ref);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            divisor++;
        }
        dividend++;
    } while (dividend);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have never programmed AVR processors, so I consulted the AVR Instruction Set Manual (Atmel 2016) for available instructions. The instruction set is designed to allow easy construction of multi-byte arithmetic by linking through the carry flag. Left shifts of multi-byte operands can be accomplished with an initial left shift on the least signficant byte, followed by a rotate left for each of the higher order bytes. Each rotate takes in the carry bit at the least significant bit, and moves the most signficant bit to the carry bit. Multi-byte comparisons are constructed from an initial compare that outputs a borrow into the carry bit, followed by compare-with-carry instructions for the higher order bytes. Subtractions work in analogous fashion.

Due to a lack of an AVR platform and AVR development tools the assembly code below was written by guessing at assembly language conventions for things such as labels and comments and is untested.

```
;;------------------------------------------------------------
;; AVR 32 / 16 -> 16 bit division by the non-performing method
;; 
;; input:    r3:r2:r1:r0 dividend --> rem:quot
;;           r5:r4       divisor
;; output:   r1:r0       quotient
;; destroys: r0, r1, r2, r3, r6
;;------------------------------------------------------------

    ldi  r6, 16 ; bits = 16
0:
    lsl  r0     ; shift
    rol  r1     ;  rem:quot 
    rol  r2     ;   left 
    rol  r3     ;    by 1
    brcs 1f     ; if carry out, rem > divisor
    cp   r2, r4 ; is rem less
    cpc  r3, r5 ;  than divisor ?
    brcs 2f     ; yes, when carry out
1:  
    sub  r2, r4 ; compute
    sbc  r3, r5 ;  rem -= divisor
    ori  r0, 1  ; record quotient bit as 1
2:
    dec  r6     ; bits--
    brne 0b     ; until bits == 0
```

Comment: Godbolt has AVR-gcc.  https://godbolt.org/z/qjYqnr.  I emits much more code, not sure why...

Comment: @PeterCordes I never noticed, thanks for the pointer. The reason its much more code is because it doesn't recognize the 32-bit left shift in my C-code, and translates it quite literally. Plus its hard to realize my carry *variable* wants to be the carry *flag*.